# How do I change the font and/or background color of text file thumbnail previews?

Tags: fonts

In Kubuntu in a night mode theme, previews for .txt and plain text files are given proper thumbnails, but the thumbnail has white text on a white background and is nearly impossible to see, much less read.

[image: screenshot]

In that screenshot, the .cfg and .ini files show a proper text file preview because their default fonts are in an acceptable color, but the .txt file is white on white. (All three files have identical content.) If you open it in an image editor, you can actually change the colors around and see the text there, but it's nearly invisible normally.

Is there a way I can change the font color for .txt file thumbnails?